# How to implement Resource/Day view (e.g. Show columns on Day view for each staff member)

Tags: fullcalendar

We are currently using an old version of FullCalendar with a custom “fork” of FullCalendar that adds support for the “ResourceDay” view (the way it shows columns on Day view for each staff member).

We want to upgrade to FullCalendar 2.x and i have a question. Is it possible to implement Resource/Day view (e.g. Show columns on Day view for each staff member) using the custom view approach in FullCalendar 2.x (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/)

We would really appreciate your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to wait for the official timeline view. You can read about it [here](http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2015/02/timeline-and-other-news.html).

Basically it will be a resource-like view that will probably cost money unless your project is under GPL. But it will be an official and robust version and *way* less work than building it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source forks of this that have tried adding it. Look at these tickets: 
https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490
https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150#c31

Some of which are not available now, or available but have issues compiling.
This is a jQuery plugin that might help you: https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView

But it has nothing to do with Fullcalendar. If you are wanting its event model to interface with your application then this might not work for you.